# Running svelte dev on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, svelte

I am running svelte like this on my server:

```
$ npm run dev


  Your application is ready~! 

  - Local:      http://localhost:5000

────────────────── LOGS ──────────────────
```

Which is great. However, when I try to access through my public ip, the bundle is not found. I.E. When I type `<publicIP>:5000` into the browser. It doesn't show up. The port is open and accessible. Is there any way to achieve this?

The request just fails. But shouldn't it work if it's running on localhost:5000? I have set up a node server and I can indeed access it on port 5000, but it doesn't serve the files properly like `npm run dev` does.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Declare the environment variable `HOST=0.0.0.0`

```sh
HOST=0.0.0.0 npm run dev
```

inspiration / possible source: https://github.com/lukeed/sirv/issues/29#issuecomment-497907602

---

You can also modify the `dev` script in the `package.json` and prepend `HOST=0.0.0.0`

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "HOST=0.0.0.0 rollup -c -w",
    "start": "sirv public"
  },
```

And now you can simply run `npm run dev`

Comment: Can you just tell me how you figured that out?

Comment: I thought svelte used `sirv` in the back, so I googled how to do it for `sirv`. I'm still not sure it really uses sirv, it might just be a lucky standard, that's why the *possible source* is there

Answer (score 28):

Actually, the message:

```
  Your application is ready~!

  - Local:      http://localhost:5000
  - Network:    Add `--host` to expose
```

is telling you to put `--host` in `sirv public` instead of `rollup -c -w` which is a bit of a confusing message.

```json
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "start": "sirv public  --host"
  },
```

Comment: While I LOVE Svelte, its little things like this that makes it so frustrating!

Comment: They should add a link to @Treedbox's answer in that message that OP quoted. I tried a whole lot of stuff before discovering this, and now it works.

Comment: `-H` is the same.

Answer (score 5):

Just add the bold part to **package.json**

> "start": "sirv public **--host 0.0.0.0**"

**UPDATE**:

```bash
npm run dev -- --host
```

Answer (score 3):

Many thx to folks with suggestions here.  Update for SvelteKit.  I just want to check the site in my local network using my mobile phone.

package.json extract...

```
"scripts": {
        "dev": "svelte-kit dev",
        "special": "svelte-kit dev --host 0.0.0.0",
        "build": "svelte-kit build",
        "preview": "svelte-kit preview",
        "lint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore ."
    },
```

And my startup console looks like:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd run-script special -- --open

> sveltekit_demo_app@0.0.1 special
> svelte-kit dev --host 0.0.0.0 "--open"

  SvelteKit v1.0.0-next.118

  network: http://192.168.1.14:3000
  network: http://192.168.56.1:3000
  network: http://169.254.131.201:3000
  local:   http://localhost:3000
```

Answer (score 0):

In ReactJS, import in `packege.json`:

```json
{
  "dev": "vite",
  "build": "vite build",
  "preview": "vite preview",
}
```