# Svelte app build but can't access localhost

Tags: svelte, tailwind-css

I am trying to setup an app with svelte and taiwlind.

I have the following

```
  "scripts": {
    "watch:tailwind": "postcss public/tailwind.css -o public/index.css -w",
    "build:tailwind": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production postcss public/tailwind.css -o public/index.css",
    "build": "npm run build:tailwind && rollup -c",
    "start": "sirv public",
    "serve": "sirv public -p 5000",
    "dev": "concurrently \"rollup -c -w\" \"npm run watch:tailwind\"",
    "autobuild": "rollup -c -w",
  },
```

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = () => ({ 
  plugins: [
    require("tailwindcss"), 
    require("autoprefixer")
  ],
});
```

rollup.config.js

```
import svelte from "rollup-plugin-svelte";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import livereload from "rollup-plugin-livereload";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import sveltePreprocess from "svelte-preprocess";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

function serve() {
  let server;

  function toExit() {
    if (server) server.kill(0);
  }

  return {
    writeBundle() {
      if (server) return;
      server = require("child_process").spawn(
        "npm",
        ["run", "start", "--", "--dev"],
        {
          stdio: ["ignore", "inherit", "inherit"],
          shell: true,
        }
      );

      process.on("SIGTERM", toExit);
      process.on("exit", toExit);
    },
  };
}

export default {
  input: "src/main.ts",
  output: {
    sourcemap: true,
    format: "iife",
    name: "app",
    file: "public/build/bundle.js",
  },
  plugins: [
    svelte({
      // enable run-time checks when not in production
      dev: !production,
      // we'll extract any component CSS out into
      // a separate file - better for performance
      css: (css) => {
        css.write("bundle.css");
      },
      preprocess: sveltePreprocess(),
    }),

    // If you have external dependencies installed from
    // npm, you'll most likely need these plugins. In
    // some cases you'll need additional configuration -
    // consult the documentation for details:
    // https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs
    resolve({
      browser: true,
      dedupe: ["svelte"],
    }),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({ sourceMap: !production }),

    // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
    // the bundle has been generated
    !production && serve(),

    // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
    // browser on changes when not in production
    !production && livereload("public"),

    // If we're building for production (npm run build
    // instead of npm run dev), minify
    production && terser(),
  ],
  watch: {
    clearScreen: false,
  },
};
```

and tailwind.cofig.js

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ["./src/**/*.svelte", "./src/**/*.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
  future: {
    purgeLayersByDefault: true,
    removeDeprecatedGapUtilities: true
  },
};
```

when I turn on the server, it build my files in public, it say started server on port 5000, but when I visit the page, it say

> This localhost page can’t be found

I do see the log in the console but they all show

> Your application is ready~!
>
> - Local:      http://localhost:5000
> - Network:    Add `--host` to expose
>
> ────────────────── LOGS ──────────────────
>
> [18:22:18] 404 ─ 2.21ms ─ /

I can't find the problem

Comment: Have you tried using `yarn start` instead of `yarn serve`?

Answer (score 0):

User `--host` on `sirv` command like `sirv public --host`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66409325/6814232

Comment: Please explain your answer