# localhost:5000 Working In Firefox But Not Chrome, Safari, And Edge

Tags: server, localhost, svelte, livereload

I've been trying to follow the ["Svelte for new developers"](https://svelte.dev/blog/svelte-for-new-developers) blog article on Svelte's website to set up a new Svelte project.

After carefully following all of the instructions and running `npm run dev`, I receive the expected output in the terminal but when I navigate to `http://localhost:5000/` in my browser (Chrome), I'm met with the message "This site can’t be reached." I receive similar error messages in Safari and Edge, but for some reason, my page loads and refreshes correctly in Firefox.

I've followed the tutorial many times and the only thing that's helped is [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63256310/12365068) that tells me to "declare the environment variable `HOST=0.0.0.0`."

My page loads and refreshes in Chrome after that, but Chrome tells me the site I'm on is not secure.

At first, I thought this was an issue with Svelte or rollup-plugin-livereload (which Svelte uses for its live reload functionality, I guess), but after some asking around for help, I was told it isn't a problem either of those but with my machine or setup.

I'm just wondering why `http://localhost:5000/` just isn't working for me as normal and if there's anything I can do to simply set up my project the way the tutorial teaches.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that your browsers default to `https` instead of `http`. See if it works if you enter the full URL to your server ie: `http://localhost:5000` and not just `localhost:5000`

Comment: Hmm... I tried that, but unfortunately, I receive the same results.